# Format word in specific column with script

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, spreadsheet, bold

I would like to format two words in my Sheet to bold after a form request. Sounds easy but I didn't find a solution till yet. Maybe someone can help out.

Description:

I copy with an onformsubmit function some of the data from the Form into an Overview sheet.

```
var overview_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");
var values = overview_sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0];
var row = overview_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

var cI = values.indexOf("I") + 1
var cRequesterInfo = values.indexOf("Request Information") + 1;

  var text = "Windows Login:\nLine Manager:\nDepartment:\nAccess Rights:";
  var requesterInformation =
    e.namedValues["Windows Login Name"] + "\n" +
    getName(e.namedValues["Line Manager E-Mail Address"]) + "\n" +
    e.namedValues["Org Code"] + "\n" +
    e.namedValues["Access Rights"] + "\n" +
    ("") + "\n" +
    ("Reason:")
    + "\n" +
    e.namedValues["Reason for Access"] + "\n" +
    ("") + "\n" +
    ("Projects:")
    + "\n" +
    e.namedValues["Access to Project/s"];

  overview_sheet.getRange(row, cI).setValue(text);
  overview_sheet.getRange(row, cRequesterInfo).setValue(requesterInformation);
```

That works fine and it looks in the sheet like

[image]

Now I try to format the word "Reason" and the word "Projects" I would like to format it to bold and if possible to make it bit bigger than the other words.

Thank you in advance for the help

Greetings
Jonas

Comment: If it's possible I  would guess you'll have to do it with richtext some how

Answer (score 0):

### Your goal:

- Take a cell's text content and format some of the words in it to make them bold.

The resulting string that you want in the cell is actually a **[`RichTextValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)**, so your goal could be redefined as:

- **How to build and set the RichTextValue of a Range?**

#### Some background:

What is a `RichTextValue`? From the docs we have the following:

> "A stylized text string used to represent cell text. Substrings of the text can have different text styles."

#### Steps:

1. Build the `RichTextValue` with [`RichTextValueBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
2. Format the RichTextValue by setting [TextStyles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#settextstylestartoffset,-endoffset,-textstyle) to the substrings.
3. Set it to the desired range

#### References:

- Class [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- Class [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- Method [Range.setRichTextValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)

Comment: Thank you I will try this :)